# Rails 3 - Model association (composition) and method delegation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, delegation, model-associations

I have the following **models** and associations:

```
class JuridicalPerson < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Supplier < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :juridical_person
  delegate  :company_name, :company_name=, :to => jurirical_person
end
```

The **controler** is:

```
def new
  @supplier = Supplier.new                                                                                                                                                 

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @supplier }
  end
end
```

The **schema** looks as follow:

```
create_table "suppliers", :force => true do |t|
  t.integer  "juridical_person_id"
  ...
end

create_table "juridical_people", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "company_name"
  ...
end
```

Now when I try to render it in a view, I get the following error:

**Supplier#company_name delegated to juridical_person.company_name, but juridical_person is nil:** #(Supplier id: nil, juridical_person_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil)

**Extracted source (around line #9):**

```
8:       <%= f.label :company_name, "Company Name" %>
9:       <%= f.text_field :company_name %>
```

Seems like the associated juridical_person is not being created at the time of delegation, but I can't figure out why. Even if I create it in the controller, the app will break when trying to update for the same reason. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

remove `=` Change

```
delegate  :company_name, :company_name=, :to => jurirical_person
```

To

```
delegate  :company_name, :company_name, :to => jurirical_person
```

Comment: Why leave two company_name delegations? Didn't work, by the way, but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
class JuridicalPerson < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :suppliers
end
```

Comment: I can't see the logic, since I'm not accessing the suppliers collection from the JuridicalPerson class. I Tried anyway and it didn't work, but thanks.

Comment: Yea, it actually looks like your problem is that you are trying to set the company_name for a juridical_person that is not yet created.  You may want to look into accepts_nested_attributes_for http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised